# How can I use the curve modifier with curves that have sharp corners?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

is there any way that I can get a mesh to follow sharp corner better. I'm using the array modifier and the curve modifier. As you can see from the image, the corner is very messy, so any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: There is no elegant automated solution for this, self intersections are hard to solve automatically and in a satisfying manner. Other than manually tweaking one workaround would be to flip the mesh to the outer contour, admitting it will not yield sharp corners.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add edgeloops or subdivide the mesh to get smooth deformation:

- Plane without Edgeloops:

[image: Plane]

[image: Plane Curve]

- Plane with Edgeloops:

[image: Plane Edgeloops]

[image: Plane Edgellops Curve]

Comment: Thank you, this is very effective for NURB curves, and if I convert my curve to a NURB curve then this loop cutting method is a good one for smoothing out bends. Unfortunately my curve is a Poly curve in the first instance and converting it to a NURB curve creates unwanted shape distortion. If I loop cut my cube 10 times, on a NURB curve it creates a very nice smoothed out bend, but if I use this on my Poly curve it behaves as if I've just made one loop cut on one side of my cube.

Answer (score 1):

I just found answer to my and probably your question -
You want to subdivide your curve to have sharper edges on modified mesh.

- **No subdivision:**

[image]

- **After I subdivided curve about 100 times:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase curve resolution preview will help with your issue

Comment: I can't get my curve to increase in resolution. It originated from a 2D mesh, which was converted to a curve. I tried changing the curve type to Bezier via the Set Spline Type, but any resolution change on this has no effect. If I add a Bezier circle I can see that this works very well to smooth out curves. This issue appears to be because of the handle type. So far it seem like if I change the handle type to one that will allow an increase in resolution the curve gets distorted.